# Page command bar overlaps Splitview Pane

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

In my Page I have bottom command bar, and if that command bar is open and user clicks on SplitView menu than command bar is overlaying the menu.

Below is the xaml of splitview page:

```
<SplitView  x:Name="NavigationSplitView"
                    DisplayMode="CompactOverlay"
                    IsPaneOpen="True"
                    CompactPaneLength="{StaticResource ShellCompactPaneSize}"
                    OpenPaneLength="300"
                    PaneBackground="{ThemeResource SplitViewBackgroundBrush}"
                    >

               <!--//App root frame where all content data will be loaded-->
                <Frame x:Name="rootFrame" />



            <SplitView.Pane>
             ...
           </SplitView.Pane></SplitView>
```

Here's the how I set commandbar on my content Page which is loaded into splitview rootFrame:

```
 <Page.BottomAppBar>

    <CommandBar x:Name="AppCommandBar"
                Background="Transparent">
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Name="Save"
                          Icon="Save"
                          Label="Save"></AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton Name="Clear"
                          Icon="ClearSelection"
                          Label="Clear"></AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>

</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Please check below screenshot, I have a Splitview with Green background and you can see that commandbar is overlapping on it.

[SplitView Issue Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKL60.png)

Here is the demo application onedrive [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C62D6F31C394F473!2294&authkey=!AGYGC5z2xp9V9Hs&ithint=file%2Czip)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your content page should look like this

```
 <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock FontSize="36"
                   Text="Content Page"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
        <CommandBar x:Name="AppCommandBar" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
                <AppBarButton Name="Save"
                              Icon="Save"
                              Label="Save"></AppBarButton>
                <AppBarButton Name="Clear"
                              Icon="ClearSelection"
                              Label="Clear"></AppBarButton>
            </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        </CommandBar>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `<Page.BottomAppBar>`, move your `<CommandBar>....</CommandBar>` into the content of your content Page (in root Frame).

Comment: How can I move splitview pane content into root frame, it's acting as a menu content.

Comment: what, stack over flow messed up my answer. Edited it. I didn't mean that you should make any change to the SplitView structure, just to change things in your content XAML Page.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you kindly consider up vote my answer ? Its -1 sadly :(

Comment: I would like to do so, but don't have enough reputation.