# Splitview Pane & Page CommandBar & Keyboard overlaps each other

Tags: uwp, commandbar, splitview

When I use SplitView and CommandBar, I put CommandBar in Page.BottomAppBar, but the CommandBar overlaps SplitView Pane. So I move the CommandBar to the page's content(Like: [Page command bar overlaps Splitview Pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36860450/page-command-bar-overlaps-splitview-pane)). It's working.

But it take a new question. When in the page the keyboard is showing, the keyboard overlaps the CommandBar. I want to show the CommandBar when the keyboard is showing.How can I do it?

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can give a workground here, maybe it's a little bit duffer, but it can solve your problem.

Since CommandBar in `Page.BottomAppBar` will not be hinden when the software keyboard is visible, but it overlaps the SplitView Pane, we can keep the `CommandBar` in the Content of `Grid`, but make a copy of this `CommandBar` and put it into the `Page.BottomAppBar`, in the meanwhile make it collapsed at first, for example like this:

```xml
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar x:Name="AppCommandBarCopy" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Name="SaveCopy"
                          Icon="Save"
                          Label="Save"></AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton Name="ClearCopy"
                          Icon="ClearSelection"
                          Label="Clear"></AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Then in the code behind, we can detect if the software keyboard is visible or not, if the keyboard is visible, show this copy; if not, hide this copy, for example here:

```cs
public SplitViewCommandBarKeyboard()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Showing += OnKeyboardShowing;
    InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Hiding += OnKeyboardHidding;
}

private void OnKeyboardHidding(InputPane sender, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs args)
{
    AppCommandBarCopy.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

private void OnKeyboardShowing(InputPane sender, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs args)
{
    AppCommandBarCopy.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: @LabanLiaoL, you're welcome! So if this is an acceptable answer, could you please mark this as answer?